# DateTime.Now in XAML without binding

Tags: c#, xaml, datetime, xamarin.forms

Can I put the date of today in a label without binding it in XAML, something like

```
<Label Text="DateTime.Now, StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'"/>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> Can I put the date of today in a label without binding it in XAML

No, you can't.

For Binding, use

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

with

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'}" />
```

---

Though, you can set it from Code behind like `myLabelControl.Content = DateTime.Now;`, but I would totally avoid this.

Comment: This binding not updating time. Like if i add new Label, it show previous date

Comment: I used .NetStandard so I used this:
`xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"`

Comment: to be clear, you CAN put the current date in a label without a binding: `<Label Content="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" />`. however, if you want to format the date, you do need the binding.

Comment: hmmmm, this works:  `<Label Content="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}" ContentStringFormat="d/M/yyyy" />`  Label does not have a StringFormat property, because 'Content' is an object, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

For me below code works

```
<Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='{0:dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm}'}" />
```

i have added below namespave in ContentPage tag

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Content property does not exist in Xamarin.Forms so i replace "Content" by "Text".

Answer (score 0):

It works by referencing the following assembly in xaml content page:

`xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"`

And I formatted the date as under:

```
<Label Text="{ Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='{0: dd MMMM yyyy}'}" />
```